# "single point of failure" job tracker node goes down and Map jobs are either running or writing the output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to hadoop and I would like to know what happens when a "single point of failure" job tracker node goes down and Map jobs are either running or writing the output.  Would the Jobtracker starts all mapjobs all over again ?

Answer (score 0):

Job tracker is a single point of failure meaning if it goes down you wont be able to submit any additional Map/reduce jobs and existing jobs would be killed.

When you restart your job tracker, you would need to resubmit whole job again.